# Remove Individual Files When Multiple FIles Are Selected With File Input

Tags: javascript, html, file

Is it possible to remove individual files from the list of files to be uploaded when the user is allowed to select multiple files? For example, I have an input that looks somewhat like that:

```
<input type = 'file' name = 'file' id = 'file' multiple = 'multiple' />
```

And the user selects 4 photos, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg and 4.jpg. Is it possible to remove 4.jpg, because the user changed their mind and doesn't want to upload that one?

Comment: You are talking about using Javascript, right? You should tag it as that if that's the case (and I don't know of another way to handle it otherwise).

Comment: I'm sorry, to remove by what exactly user action? If he clicks on that input control again, he may just choose the list of files again.

Comment: Take note that browsers are usually very restrictive about what may be actually changed by JavaScript in the `input=file` control value.

Comment: http://imgdiode.com/MiB9QK The file should be removed when the red "x" is clicked.

Comment: How the names of the files are written here? Are these the files already uploaded?

Comment: No, I use jQuery's .val() to get the name of the files and display them.

Comment: Why don't you generate a new file upload element after the last finishes, and let them remove the individual upload elements as they wish? That seems the easiest, unless the answer to this is stupid-easy.

Comment: I could, but I would rather stay away from that if at all possible.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, there's probably libraries that would help with this. I see the utility of multi-file uploads. If you can't literally do it, you could offer them a list and let them "uncheck" a file to *store*, which you then ignore on the server on upload. In other words, they mark it for "ignore" and the server discards it due to that.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing that if all else fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer would be just 'No'. [It's not possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input#File_inputs) to change the value of `file input` element from a script: it would be a security hole size of a mammoth otherwise. And let me assure you: some browsers (IE, that's about you!) become VERY picky when dealing with file inputs.

But you can use the following approach: let users upload as many files as you and they want (it's prudent to set some limits, though), but put them into some temporary storage. Only when users actually express their desire to save the entity to which these files are attached, move these files into a permanent state.

Or may be it's time to think about using some fallback mechanisms, Flash or something like that. In fact, there's another reason to do it: IE8 doesn't support `multiple` attribute on the file picker.