# Edit files selected in input type file in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using simple HTML form field to submit files and images.I am uploading multiple files from single input [type=file] using multiple attributes. my problem is that once I select my files from file browser it add multiple files in that input field but I need to remove some file from selected one how could I do..?

Ex:-  I have selected 4 images to upload and preview it on browser but want to remove 2 images how could I do this by using javascript or Jquery.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: show me your code

Comment: I think this question has already been answered,
[check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062876/removing-file-from-multiple-files-uploader-on-button-click-when-using-html5-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing file from multiple files uploader on button click when using HTML5 file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062876/removing-file-from-multiple-files-uploader-on-button-click-when-using-html5-file)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062876/removing-file-from-multiple-files-uploader-on-button-click-when-using-html5-file) this link only hide the image shown in UI , After submission of form all images including removed images get stored .. means not able to remove attached img / file