# remove value of the input type:file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I have

```
<input id="seleccion" name="archivos" multiple type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" />
```

I need to delete one of the files (one by one)

```
function EliminaArchivo(item){
 $("#seleccion").vall(null);
}
```

this empties the input file completely and I need to delete only the file with the index that I'm passing as a parameter to my function.

```
file1 [0]    //here button for delete this file                                                                   
file2 [1]    //here button for delete this file                                    
file3 [2]    //here button for delete this file
```

i need remove file1 [1]...

Comment: that means you most likely have non-unique ids...make them unique...e.g. <input id="seleccion1" name="archivos" multiple type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" /><input id="seleccion2" name="archivos" multiple type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" />

Comment: but is multiple selection my input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062876/removing-file-from-multiple-files-uploader-on-button-click-when-using-html5-file

Comment: why do you need this ? do you need the remaining files list for some other computation ?

Comment: This is for a page web. Where (users) they will select files to upload them to a server but, they will have the option of deleting some of their selected files if they wish, the example that you passed to me is very good, I was reviewing it, it is similar to what I need.

Comment: you can't remove items from the actual `input.files` collection, but you can dupe the files to an array and splice that to use to the UI and server interaction.